# mysql get column but not include empty column

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I would like to select all column from tbl1 but not column that has empty data in MySQL store procedure.

My structure as the following:

```
tbl1
Name  val1  val2 val3 val4
a      1           2
b      4           4
c      5           7
e      7           6
```

select * from tbl1 where .....

```
Result:
    Name  val1  val3 
    a      1      2
    b      4      4
    c      5      7
    e      7      6
```

Comment: what to do if some column is partially filled

Comment: Why do you need this? What are you trying to achieve? In SQL object identifiers (table, column names etc.) are constant literals. You can't  manipulate with or inject them in a normal query. You can possibly overcome this with dynamic SQL, but does it really worth it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it. Assumption is that by *...column that has empty data...* you mean a column with `NULL` values for all rows.

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_select()
BEGIN
    SET @tbl = 'tbl1', @sql = NULL, @cols = NULL;
    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(
        CONCAT(
          'SELECT ''',
          `column_name`,
          ''' name, COUNT(',
          `column_name`, ') n FROM ',
          @tbl
        )
      SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ') INTO @sql
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE table_name = @tbl;

    SET @sql = CONCAT(
                 'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) INTO @cols FROM (', 
                 @sql, 
                 ') q WHERE q.n > 0'
               );
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;

    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', @cols, ' FROM ', @tbl);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then you call the procedure

```sql
CALL sp_select();
```

And you'll get

```
+------+------+------+
| Name | val1 | val3 |
+------+------+------+
| a    |    1 |    2 |
| b    |    4 |    4 |
| c    |    5 |    7 |
| e    |    7 |    6 |
+------+------+------+
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c2a50/1)** demo.